# How to get the sum of two numbers in an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecondPlusThird {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            if (number == 0) {
                break;
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(numbers.get();
        
    }
}
```

I tried it with `System.out.println(numbers.get(1)+(2));`

But it didn't work. I have to print the sum of the second and third numbers given by the user.

Comment: To get an element by index from an `ArrayList` use `list.get(index)`. To get two elements, use `list.get(1) + list.get(2)`.

Comment: `numbers.get(1)+(2)` this just takes the second number (`get` starts at 0) and a literal two and sums them.

Comment: Also, you're not putting anything in `numbers`

Comment: As an aside "But it didn't work" is not a problem statement that can be acted upon. I mean, in this case it's easy to see what's wrong with your code, but in the future please describe your inputs, your expected result (this you did correctly) and what happens instead (exceptions, compiler error, wrong results). The more detail you add, the more likely people are to want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do sum of two numbers, i would recommend you to use an array.
Arraylist is dynamic array & you are not utilizing its potential so don't use it.

Anyways, if you still want to do it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
a1.add(1);
a1.add(2);

sum = a1.get(0) + a1.get(1);
```